# Search for multiple strings in a text file in c#

Tags: c#

Want to search a string in a file, once found, I would like to go previous and search for a different string and finally get the trailing characters of the string.

Let's say my text in the file goes like

line 1 ------------ sample text counterparty="ABCD" detailsprogrammed... so on

line 2 ------------ this is line two product="12345" and continues

I want to first search for 12345 which is unique. Once found I want to go to the previous line and search for first occurance of counterparty and once found I would like to capture the string ABCD

Comment: Why you just don't read from end of file to first line?

Comment: You show two lines, where is your 3 lines back logic? What have you tried?

Comment: This smells of homework... :)

Answer (score 2):

You could just cache the line prior for each iteration:

```
string prevLine = "";
while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.contains("12345"))
    {
        textIWant = prevLine.Substring( //..etc
    }
    prevLine = line;
}
```

You could continue the same pattern if you need to go more than 1 line back, but obviously it gets messy if you need to go back more than 1 or 2.  If the file isn't that big you could also read the whole thing and just cache all the lines, but this would not be good if the files can be very large and thus take up a large chunk of memory to cache all at once.

Comment: _" I would like to go 3 lines back "_

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yeah I decided to answer his example question, since that is what he gave specifics on

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions (System.Text.RegularExpressions). First read in a chunk of lines and concat them together. Then pass them to the Match method of a Regex object.

Assuming you want to go back three lines you could do something like this.

```
Regex RX = new Regex(@"counterparty=""([^""]*)"" (.*?\n){3}product=""12345""",
       RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Match M = RX.Match(YourString);

if (M.Success)
     strCounterParty = M.Result("${1}");  //Returns the value between the 1st set of ()'s
```

This way you will only match the product number and not some other value that happens to be 12345 as well.